# Differences in faculty job talks for current faculty vs. new graduates? (especially for STEM fields with large research groups)

Tags: faculty-application

Is there any standard advice about how a job talk from a junior faculty member (e.g. let's say 2 years in) should differ from someone who is fresh on the market?

For instance, I've heard it's good to go into technical depth on one project in your job talk, but this might be less important / essential as a faculty member, as you are more expected to be supervising many projects.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that the question at hand differs less than you might think it does. What matters more is who the audience will be. If it is a talk to a general departmental audience, including students, then a general talk about your research area is probably best, since one of the criteria is how you appeal to students.

But if the audience is a small number of specialists in your field then a more technical talk is warranted, including the open questions you still see in your area and intend to address in the future.

Of course, the junior faculty member is probably better placed for the second sort of talk.

Ask who the audience will be if you don't already know. In fact, knowing your audience is always a good idea for any talk. Address the audience, not just the field.

Comment: Assuming this is a job talk, the audience might be “anyone who shows up” but the decision makers in the audience are likely the voting faculty in the department. How does that figure into your answer?

Comment: Actually, @Dawn, I'd suggest the same. Know your audience. Even the decision makers will be taking account of the reception. Or should be, anyway. A sit down with a few specialists is fine for a geeky talk, but maybe not for an open one. Even a zoom presentation might be viewed differently if people drop out after a  while.